# What kind of object does the `pipe` method accept?

Tags: node.js

I have the following code:

```
    process.stdin.pipe(output).pipe(socket);
```

I want to modify the contents of `output` before it is piped into `socket`. I need to add an additional `pipe` in between the two, but I am not sure how to do that. I checked the documentation on [Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) but I could not figure out how to create my own method to invoke `pipe` with that will intercept the current pipeline.

What kind of object does the `pipe` method accept?

Comment: The object is a node.js stream object.  You may be interested in a [stream transform](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html).

Comment: Why does your question title and last line reference `pipeline` when the method in your code is `.pipe()`?